# Provide fallback in Docker Compose service when env_file is used?

Tags: docker

`.env.local`:

```
FOO=bar
```

I'm loading `.env.local` as service `env_file`. I want to still provide a fallback value if `FOO` is missing or empty:

```yaml
services:
  caddy:
    env_file: [.env.local]
    image: caddy
    environment:
      FOO: ${FOO:-baz}
```

No matter what, `FOO` is always `baz`, even if it should be, at the best of my knowledge, `bar`:

```
$ docker compose config

name: myproject
services:
  caddy:
    environment:
      FOO: baz
    image: caddy
```

I know that `environment` takes precedence over `env_file`, but I'm referencing `FOO` itself, so I'd bet it would work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Interestingly it works when using an env file called `.env`...

Comment: It also works for me if I run `docker compose --env-file .env.local config`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `environment` field in the Docker Compose file has indeed a higher precedence than the `env_file` field. This means that if an environment variable is defined in both places, the value from the `environment` field will be used.

In your case, the `FOO` variable is defined in both the `env_file` and `environment` fields.
The `FOO` variable in the `environment` field is set to `${FOO:-baz}`, which means "use the value of `FOO` if it is set and not empty, otherwise use `baz`".

> I know that environment takes precedence over env_file, but I'm referencing FOO itself, so I'd bet it would work.": what did I miss?

You are expecting the `FOO` variable in the `environment` section would take the value from the `FOO` variable defined in the `env_file` if it exists, and use the fallback value `baz` otherwise.
However, this is not how Docker Compose works.

At the time Docker Compose is processing the `environment` field, it has not yet processed the `env_file` field, so it does not know about the `FOO` variable defined there. As a result, it treats `FOO` as unset and uses the fallback value `baz`.

The `.env` file is a special case. Docker Compose automatically reads this file, if it exists, before processing the rest of the Docker Compose file. That's why defining `FOO` in `.env` works as you expected.

The `--env-file` option also works because it tells Docker Compose to read the specified file before processing the Docker Compose file, similar to how it automatically reads `.env`.

If you want to use a fallback value for an environment variable that is defined in an `env_file`, you will need to either define the variable in `.env` or use the `--env-file` option.

Comment: This Is what I was afraid of. Some frameworks define secrets in env.local file so having both.env and . local behave the same would be great. With the logic you described I'm forced to put default values in service entrypoints. Kinda ugly but works. Thanks!